# Retrieve data from two tables in mysql. There is only one common column between the two tables

Tags: mysql

I have a table "ttquestion" which has columns 'qId', 'question', 'option1', 'option2', 'option3', 'difficulty'. The primary key is 'qId'.
I have another table "level" which has columns 'userId' and 'qId'. There is no primary key in this table.

I have to retrieve data from "ttquestion" and the below query is working fine. Now the query has to be modified such that I should get 12 records from "ttquestion" and should exclude 'qId' present in the table "level" for a specfic user.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT * FROM ttquestion WHERE difficulty='1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4) 
    UNION ALL 
    (SELECT * FROM ttquestion WHERE difficulty='2' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4) 
    UNION ALL 
    (SELECT * FROM ttquestion WHERE difficulty='3' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4)
) 
ttquestion ORDER BY difficulty;
```

Kindly suggest as I am not good at SQL queries.

Comment: See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `NOT EXISTS` clause in each subquery to filter out the 'qId' values that exist in the "level" table for a specific user.

```
SELECT * FROM (
   (SELECT * FROM ttquestion
   WHERE difficulty='1' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM level WHERE level.qId = ttquestion.qId AND level.userId = 'exampleID')
   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4)
   UNION ALL
   (SELECT * FROM ttquestion
   WHERE difficulty='2' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM level WHERE level.qId = ttquestion.qId AND level.userId = 'exampleID')
   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4)
   UNION ALL
   (SELECT * FROM ttquestion
   WHERE difficulty='3' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM level WHERE level.qId = ttquestion.qId AND level.userId = 'exampleID')
   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4)
) ttquestion ORDER BY difficulty;
```

replace `'exampleID''` with the actual user ID . this modified query ensures that the selected 'qId' values do not exist in the "level" table for the specified user.